# Running out of memory for django

Tags: python, linux, django, memory

So I recently SSHed into my linode Django server and whenever I try to do anything it ends up getting killed for running out of memory. After a little exploration I found this little gem (the output of top):[image]

It seems I somehow hove many instance of apache and python open all at once eating up all my memory. Is this normal behavior for Django? How could this have happened? What do I do to fix my memory shortage?

Comment: It seems that your Apache server spawns some handler processes? That's possibly normal (for Apache at least) and wrong at the same time. First of all I advice using nginx. But the memory leak is probably unrelated to that fact. Most likely you have an issue with your code.

Comment: This is Apache's way of staying reactive, it pre-forks workers to handle incoming requests instead of making the client wait for the fork to occur.

Comment: It seems to be consuming an absurd amount of memory. Where can I turn off prefork?

Comment: @lemiant Switch to nginx + uwsgi.